# What is the difference between host header and public url in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am creating a new web Application in sharepoint 2010.What is the difference between host header and public url in Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

The public URL is what's being used by SharePoint to render your content correctly and to assure a consistent URL experience.
[Find your answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40328/zones-aam-host-headers)